# How to create nested array attribute

Tags: theme-development, block-editor

I want to create a nested array attribute but not sure how.

I think the JSON would look something like this. I want to have a tab with multiple tiles inside each tab.

```
{
  "tabs": [
    {
      "tabTitle": "Tab One",
      "tiles": [
        {
          "tileTitle": "Tile one Tab one",
          "tileContent": "",
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "tabTitle": "Tab Two",
      "tiles": [
        {
          "tileTitle": "Tile one tab two",
          "tileContent": "",
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I am not sure if the above is correct but if so, how would I create the Gutenberg attributes for this? What I found looks like the below but not sure if this is in fact a nested array:

```
  attributes: {
    tabs: {
      type: "array",
      default: [""],
      query: {
        tabTitle: {
          type: "string",
        },
        tiles: {
          type: "array",
          default: [],
        },
      },
    },
   },
```

This is how far I have got. I am able to create new tabs but I am struggling with the tiles inside the tabs part..

```
import { registerBlockType } from "@wordpress/blocks";
import { useState } from "react";
import {
  RichText,
  URLInputButton,
  InspectorControls,
  ColorPalette,
} from "@wordpress/block-editor";
import { Button } from "@wordpress/components";
const __ = wp.i18n.__;

registerBlockType("custom/tabs", {
  title: __("Tabbed Blocks", "custom-blocks"),
  description: __("Tabbed content blocks", "custom-blocks"),
  icon: "smiley",
  category: "custom-category",
  keywords: [__("tabs", "custom-blocks"), __("repeat", "custom-blocks")],
  attributes: {
    tabs: {
      type: "array",
      default: [""],
    },
    tiles: {
      type: "array",
      default: [""],
    },
  },

  edit: (props) => {
    const {
      attributes: { tabs, tiles },
      setAttributes,
    } = props;

    console.log(tabs);

    const [showTab, setShowTab] = useState("");

    const handleTabClick = (index) => {
      setShowTab(index);
    };

    return (
      <>
        <div className="tabs">
          <ul id="tabs-nav">
            {tabs.map((t, index) => (
              <li>
                <span onClick={() => handleTabClick(index)} id={`#tab${index}`}>
                  <RichText
                    placeholder="Tab title"
                    onChange={(tabTitle) => {
                      const newObject = Object.assign({}, t, {
                        tabTitle: tabTitle,
                      });
                      setAttributes({
                        tabs: [
                          ...tabs.filter((item) => item.index != t.index),
                          newObject,
                        ],
                      });
                    }}
                    value={t.tabTitle}
                  />
                </span>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
          {tabs.map((t, index) => (
            <div
              id={`tab${index}`}
              className={
                showTab == index ? `tab-content show` : `tab-content hide`
              }
            >
              <div className="home-tabs">
                {tiles.map((tile, index) => (
                  <div className="tab-block">
                    <div className="copy">
                      <RichText
                        tagName="h3"
                        placeholder="Tab Content Title"
                        onChange={(tabTileTitle) => {
                          const newObject = Object.assign({}, t, {
                            tileTitle: tabTileTitle,
                          });
                          setAttributes({
                            //
                          });
                        }}
                        value={tile.tabTileTitle}
                      />
                      <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
                        sed at ante. Mauris eleifend, quam a vulputate dictum.
                      </p>
                      <p>
                        <a href="">
                          read more
                        </a>
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                ))}
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
          {/* <Button
            onClick={() => {
              setAttributes({
                tiles: [...tiles, { index: tiles.length }],
              });
            }}
          >
            Add Tile
          </Button> */}
        </div>
        <Button
          onClick={() => {
            setAttributes({
              tabs: [...tabs, { index: tabs.length }],
            });
            console.log(tabs);
          }}
        >
          Add Tab
        </Button>
      </>
    );
  },
  save: (props) => {
    return null;
  },
});
```

[image]

Comment: are you sure this is the correct approach? Shouldn't each tab be a separate block with a container block named Tabs?

Comment: I built the block initially using ACF where I have a repeater field for the tabs and another repeater inside that repeater for each tile inside the tab. So, I have many tiles inside each tab. When I looked at the API endpoint for it I got the JSON response I posted first in my question. So, I am trying to drop ACF and build a native block using React with the same idea ie: repeater inside a repeater but the struggle is endless.

Comment: that's because you're not meant to do it that way, if you have 5 things, that's 5 blocks, not 1 block with 5 sub-attributes. Look at how columns work, you have a columns block that contains individual column blocks. There's no columns attribute containing each column and its content. Abandon the concept of "repeater fields" it doesn't make sense and isn't necessary when building blocks, and will cause you hassle and confusion that's easily avoided. Nested blocks are what you should look at

Comment: @TomJNowell I added an image of how I want it to work, hopefully this explains it better than my words

Comment: yup what you want is impossible with the approach you have taken, you will need to implement each tab as a separate block that supports nested blocks so that there can be child blocks. Any approach at all that relies on a content attribute is a dead end that will never give you what your image shows. Otherwise if you managed to solve your current dilemma you would run face first into a brick wall trying to recreate a mini block editor inside each tab and saving the results into HTML to put in your attribute

Comment: By nested blocks do you mean putting `<InnerBlocks />` inside the tab?

Comment: You need a tabs block, and a tab block with a title attribute. That gives you everything you need to create content then style them as tabs on the frontend. Once you've done that it's just a matter of styling and adjusting the block editor UI

Comment: yes, there is no way to do this nicely without nested/child/inner blocks. You will also want a working save component, not a function that returns `null`

Comment: a big difference is that ACF lets you "configure" your output via a set of forms and fields, here you need to "compose" your content. It's more analogous to extremely advanced shortcodes

Comment: I am returning null because my php is returning the output using `render_callback` in `register_block_type`. Basically using JSX for admin and php for frontend

Comment: @TomJNowell I would still like to be able to click a button to add tabs and then have the `<InnerBlock/>` inside there when a user can choose any block/s to add inside the tab. I think this is along the lines of what you mentioned. Adding `<InnerBlock/>` inside a loop though is also a problem. I downloaded an existing plugin with tabs and they have this where you click to add a tab and you can add any blocks inside that. I tried to look at the implementation  but everything is minified. Anyway, thanks for your guidance. I have opened a new question regarding this.

Comment: I do not understand why wanting a dedicated button to insert additional block would change things? Re-read what I said, a Tabs block that contains tab blocks that contain content. Take another look at literally any block in Gutenberg that comes with core that contains thing and you'll see they have inserter buttons. Just because you want to move the inserter buttons around in the UI doesn't mean you have to re-engineer how blocks work. It would be like rewriting your entire site to change styling and ignoring that CSS exists